# Improve this statement using ISNULL

Tags: sql-server, isnull

Beginner with SQL and trying to improve this using `ISNULL` instead of the longer statement?

```
CASE WHEN c.FirstName IS NULL THEN '' ELSE c.FirstName END
```

Comment: You may also be interested in `COALESCE`, see  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 3):

You can simply replace the whole statement with `ISNULL(c.FirstName, '')` as per the [docs on the `ISNULL()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

The first parameter is the value being checked for null, and the second parameter is the replacement value to return when the first parameter is null.